# What is the alternative to getimagesize () which is disabled on a shared server

Tags: php, getimagesize

When I use getimagesize() in my hosting company which is a shared server, I get the following error.

```
Message: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration

Filename: admin/admin_product_home.php
```

What is the alternative to get the image size of images?

Thanks in advance.

```
echo "<tr>\n";
    echo "<td>".$list."</td>\n";
            $filepath = base_url()."uploads/".$list;
            echo "<td><img width=\"70px\" src='".$filepath."' /></td>";
            echo "<td>";
            $filesize = getimagesize($filepath);
    echo "width: ".$filesize[0]. "px<br />";
    echo "height: ".$filesize[1]. "px<br />";
            echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
        ...
        ...
```

I am using codeigniter as you can see in base_url().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem isn't with `getimagesize` but with the file name you are trying to open.

It looks like you're using a `http://` URL in the `getimagesize()` call, despite the file name you quote saying otherwise.

Make sure you are using a local file path.

**Edit:** Create a file path variable without `base_url()` and prepend the correct filesystem path.

Comment: Thanks Pekka. The following code is working. $filepath = base_url()."uploads/".$list; $imagepath = "uploads/".$list; echo "<td><img width=\"70px\" src='".$filepath."' /></td>"; echo "<td>";$filesize = getimagesize($imagepath);
echo "width: ".$filesize[0]. "px<br />";echo "height: ".$filesize[1]. "px<br />";.........